# Travel from Peru to Mexico connecting in US

Tags: usa, air-travel, transit, peruvian-citizens

Can a Peru passport holder flying from Peru to Cancun, Mexico take a flight with a plane change in the US.?
International travel

Comment: Yes it is but that answer was from 2012. Further investigation reveals that the answer is the same: a US visa is absolutely required even for a short connection via a US airport if the traveler holds only a Peruvian passport.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, provided you have a current US visa.

Peru does not participate in the Visa Waiver Program so a visa is required to enter the United States. This is the case for all connections as no US airport has a transit zone.

Note, the visa refusal rate for Peru is quite low, ~20%. Whether or not it's worth applying is something only you can determine.

Comment: Thank you for this observation. Would the refusal rate be as low if a a B-2 visitors visa were sought for a future trip?

Comment: Why would they need an ESTA (or how could they obtain one) if they need a visa?

Comment: *provided you have a US Visa and current ESTA* - I thought ESTA was only required if you were entering under VWP, so if they have a Visa then ESTA shouldn't be a requirement?

Comment: Doh!  You are right, I'd blame auto correct but my bad.  Funny, I totally would have take a downvote on that since for once, it would have been legit.

Comment: @Rider0109 Well, all visas are for future trips.  The point is, barring extreme circumstances, Peruvian applicants should expect to be approved.